# Cannot flash Galaxy Nexus ('maguro') device

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I've got a problem when tried to flash my android.

My phone was already unlocked. I performed factory reset and after enable developer mode.

Here code from terminal:

```
mikalai@mikalai-HP-Compaq-6000-Pro-SFF-PC:~$ sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=trusty
2014/03/12 18:36:23 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
2014/03/12 18:36:23 Device is |maguro|
2014/03/12 18:36:24 Flashing version 188 from trusty channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device maguro
2014/03/12 18:36:25 Start pushing /home/mikalai/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2014/03/12 18:36:25 Start pushing /home/mikalai/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2014/03/12 18:36:25 Start pushing /home/mikalai/.cache/ubuntuimages/trusty/maguro/version-188.tar.xz to device
2014/03/12 18:36:25 Cannot push /home/mikalai/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
```

If anybody know what I did wrong, please advise. Thank you for any help.

Comment: So, I finally flash my devise using `phablet-flash`, but it really slow, I think it because of processor and only 1024GB RAM, in Google Nexus 4 Phone spec more better [see comparison](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Google-Nexus-4,Samsung-GALAXY-Nexus/phones/7531,5595)

Comment: Using **phablet flash** won't be using the newest 'AOSP 4.4.2' based build, which is faster. *But your right, the **Nexus 4** has more performance.*

Comment: Yeah, I know, but you can update version after flash.

Comment: **No.** To use the latest build, you need to re-install. It is quite different version. *I don't recommend trying to retain settings, media files, or call data.* ***Backup data, off the device.***

Comment: Oh, I see. Its explain a lot... Will try new one then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### What device do you have?

(a.) Samsung **Galaxy Nexus** ('maguro')

(b.) LG **Nexus 4** ('mako')

---

**Assuming that does NOT matter ..**

You should verify device is 'online', with

```
adb devices
```

Then Try:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=trusty --bootstrap
```

Comment: My is Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Answer (score 0):

Im wondering you flash the device in ADB while your device is on android. The best way turn device to bootloader, connect to pc via usb and bootstraping:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --bootstrap --device=maguro #or other nexus device unless nexus one and nexus s
```

This you will get live "stable" ubuntu touch for your device. After device have ubuntu touch live. It's easy to change channels:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --list-channels 
ubuntu-device-flash --device=maguro --channel=saucy-custoized --bootstrap
```

Note: bootstrap command usable only on booatloader / fastboot mode.

Comment: seems that the trick is to use  --channel=trusty